How can I fix my audio for my laptop speaker?
Sound plays in wired earbuds but not in speakers when the earphones are unplugged. I didn't have this problem until today, and I don't remember doing anything to make cause this. I've of course restarted my laptop multiple times, and I have checked Alsamixer and everything seemed fine. I use pipewire, but there's a problem I have noticed. When I run the command to check the systemctl status pipewire I get the error Unit pipewire.service could not be found. Yet I have pipewire installed, and when I try to uninstall it says it won't because it breaks a bunch of dependencies. I don't know whether it's a problem with pipewire or something else but if anyone has any solutions please let me know.

Have you checked bluetoothctl? I also use pipewire, and have found that on some systems the "connect" action happens automatically - but on others it does not.

I've never used that before so I had to install the dependencies. it returned bluetoothctl  [bluetooth]# hci0 new_settings: bondable ssp br/edr le secure-conn wide-band-speech  [bluetooth]# Agent registered [bluetooth]# [CHG] Controller B4:0E:DE:37:E4:BA Pairable: yes [bluetooth]# 

Yeah, you're a GUI user I guess... you can enter help at the prompt to learn what's possible. What I would enter first is devices Connected. That will/should tell you whether your earphones or speakers (or either) are connected. You can then use the connect <dev> command to try to connect the one you want to connect to. And <dev> is a string like B8:F6:53:9B:1A:97. For example, on  my system, if I enter devices Connected, I get: Device B8:F6:53:9B:1A:97 JBL Flip 5

I reverted your most recent edit, where you appeared to add an answer to the text of the question and where you tagged the title with "Fixed".  Accepting a given answer will automatically mark the issue as resolved. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Try systemctl --user status pipewire: Pipewire runs per-user-session, not per-whole-system.
So, there's no problem in that.
The laptop speaker issue: hm. Maybe the speakers specifically are muted or turned to a very low volume? To adjust volumes and change sound routing properties on a pipewire system, alsamixer is the wrong tool: It can only interact with the underlying ALSA device (which works, as we can see from your earbuds), and the emulated ALSA device atop of pipewire, but not with pipewire itself.
pavucontrol does that. Also try the different configurations on the last tab.

Okay so the command you recommended worked, but is says basically everything is working just fine to my understanding. pavucontrol was the first thing I tried, everything is turned to 100. in case it's helpful, this is what systemctl --user status pipewire returned  ● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; disabled; preset: enabled)   Active: active (running)  TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket    Main PID: 1126 (pipewire)       Tasks: 3 (limit: 38093)      Memory: 7.1M (peak: 8.2M) CPU: 3.281s

yeah, that was to be expected :) Have you checked the available configuration versions for your sound card on the rightmost tab of pavuconrol, titled "Configuration"? and, is the right output port selected for your sound card on the "Output Devices" tab?

yes, I've tried each of the options. Even when I play sounds it shows by the volume/test slider that its playing the sounds through the laptop speaker but I can't hear anything. It's worth noting it can play sound through wired earbuds and such just not through the speaker

something that may also be helpful is that I ran speaker-test -c 2 -l 10 and got (summarized because its just more of the same) the following-  Playback device is default Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels Using 16 octaves of pink noise Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz) Buffer size range from 64 to 1048576 Period size range from 32 to 524288 Periods = 4 was set period_size = 12000 was set buffer_size = 48000  0 - Front Left  1 - Front Right Time per period = 5.096810  0 - Front Left  1 - Front Right

sadly not much of help; the problem here is somewhere in how your soundcard is told to route audio to the speakers or the audio jack.; that streaming samples to the soundcard works is clear from the fact that your earbuds work. In the extreme case, the speaker amplifier is just toast; I just don't want to conclude that hardware failure is the reason you don't hear anything when there might be configuration that affects what the sound card does. That's why I was asking so persistently about settings you can see in pavucontrol!

OH MY GOODNESS I FIXED IT. I basically just copied the system files from my hard drive to my desktop. I was stupid and they were on my hard drive which is super unreliable (including system sound files), I rebooted a couple times and everything works fine now.

@BlakelySchreiber if no-one else has suggested this please add it as an answer. Then tomorrow you can accept it ✓ to show it's what worked for you
